# MS SQL Function Returns: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

My subquery returns a single value since it is a MIN().  Why am I getting the following error when I call the function?  Thanks MS SQL Server 2008

Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows...

```
Create Function dbo.ufnMinSpeed ( 
     @Track AS varchar(3),
     @Distance AS INT,
     @Surface  AS nchar(10),
     @MaxDate AS nchar (10)
) Returns Decimal(15,2) As
Begin

Declare @MinSpeed Decimal(15,2)

Return (
    Select Min (tr.Finaltime) Over (
        Partition By th.TrackCode, tr.Distance, tr.Surface
    ) AS MinSpeed
    From
        dbo.tblHeader th,
        dbo.tblRaceData tr,
        dbo.tblStarters ts
    Where
        th.TrackCode  = @Track And
        tr.Distance = @Distance And
        tr.Surface = @Surface And
        th.RaceDate < @MaxDate And
        tr.TrackDateRaceNumber = ts.TrackDateRaceNumber And
        th.TrackDateNumber = tr.TrackDateNumber
)

Return @MinSpeed

End
```

Comment: So what is the question? If you want to return a single decimal, having a subquery that returns multiple values is of course wrong. Which is why you get that error message....

Comment: You have many issues in your function. At first, you have two returns in main flow. Then, your query can return more than one result (one for each partition). What you want achieve in your function?

Comment: The syntax you are using for joins is not standard. While it remains valid for INNER JOINs, please consider using the ANSI standard syntax.

Comment: You also have a logic error. You are applying the MIN function to windows of rows which is why the function is returning multiple rows. Take out the `OVER` bit.

Answer (score 0):

I think this corrects all the issues outlined in the comments.

```
Create Function dbo.ufnMinSpeed ( 
    @Track varchar(3),
    @Distance int,
    @Surface nchar(10),
    @MaxDate nchar (10)
) Returns Decimal(15,2) As
Begin
    Return (
        Select
            Min (tr.Finaltime)
        From
            dbo.tblHeader th
                Inner Join
            dbo.tblRaceData tr
                On th.TrackDateNumber = tr.TrackDateNumber
                Inner Join
            dbo.tblStarters ts
                On tr.TrackDateRaceNumber = ts.TrackDateRaceNumber
        Where
            th.TrackCode = @Track And
            tr.Distance = @Distance And
            tr.Surface = @Surface And
            th.RaceDate < @MaxDate
    )
End
```